# How to run HttpClient Async method Synchronously in blazor Webassembly

Tags: asynchronous, blazor-webassembly, synchronous

I wrote this sync method that I want to run PostAsJsonAsync synchronously in it.

```
    bool result2 = false;
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse2 = null;
    void CallPostModel()
    {   
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("About to Request.");
            var httpResponse2 = client.PostAsJsonAsync<PostTestModel>
              ("api/weatherforecast/PostTest", 
new PostTestModel() { Id = 2, Name = "Michael" }).Result; //<< code executes until here
            Console.WriteLine($"Ran Successfuly");
            if (httpResponse2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response Success.");
                result2 = httpResponse2.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<bool>().Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result2}");               
                return result2;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Error from app. not success status code.");
            }
        });
    }
```

With this method, Although the server method is called. but the result is not returned, and the server code executes and this `Console.WriteLine($"Ran Successfuly");` is not executing.
So if anyone can correct this code or specify a way to do this in blazor webassembly, Run PostJsonAsync synchronously in a sync method?